# SSL certificate not after date wrong

Tags: ssl

I have a VPS and I have a website where I installed an SSL certificate.

When I check it using the below linux command I get a past notAfter date:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect mysite.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates

notBefore=Aug 23 12:39:38 2015 GMT
notAfter=Aug 23 12:39:38 2016 GMT
```

Why is the notAfter date in the past?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given the amount of information in the question one can only guess that if you access the site with a browser you get no error about an expired certificate but if you access it with `openssl s_client` you get an expired certificate.
In this case it is probably due do the use of [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) at the server and that you have a valid certificate configured for the specific virtual host you test but that you have still an expired default certificate. To access the server like the browser does you have to use SNI with openssl too by specifying the `-servername` option:

```
 openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -servername example.com
```

Comment: Yes you are right when I use your code I get 
notBefore=Jan 11 13:53:00 2017 GMT
notAfter=Jan 11 13:53:00 2018 GMT
so how can I fix the SNI issue please?

Comment: @oussamakamal: you already fixed the SNI issue by using the `-servername` option. Browsers will use SNI anyway so no fix needed there.